# Sharing Windows Authentication between SharePoint and ASP.Net Web Application

Tags: asp.net, windows, sharepoint, authentication, shared

We have a SharePoint web application that uses Windows Authentication e.g. extranet.test.com.

We also have an ASP.NET web application that uses Windows Authentication e.g. webapp.test.com

However when navigating between the two applications, users must authenticate a second time. Is there a way to prevent this?

I have searched the web but have been unable to find a suitable answer. I have seen many examples using Forms Based Authentication but this is not a viable option since we are using the Active Directory.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are both the Sharepoint and the ASP.NET app on the same server?

Comment: Yes, but it would be nice to have a solution that worked across multiple servers. Also, why would would it matter?

Comment: Honestly? I don't know why it matters. But we have a similar setup of multiple applications under the same domain, where each time you fire up an app on a different server you need to re-authenticate.

Answer (score 0):

What is the authentication scheme you are using: NTLM / Kerberos ?

1. If you are using Kerberos, you can simply enable credential delegation between two applications.
2. If  you are using NTLM, the only solution is to put them in Intranet zone. You can enforce it using Domain policy. Not that this will work only if the users are logged on to domain.